# Can I use jQuery Migrate 1.4.1 while having jQuery 1.3.1?

Tags: jquery, jquery-migrate

My website is running jQuery 1.3.1. I want to use jQuery Migrate 1.4.1 in order to migrate to a newer version of jQuery. According to the official documentation at https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/1.x-stable/README.md, I need to load the jQuery Migrate 1.4.1 after the script for jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

Since I have jQuery 1.3.1, I am using this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

My website breaks and things parts that use jQuery are not working correctly anymore. When I load the my website and go to the Console, I see this:

> JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1

However, as I mentioned, the jQuery on my website stops working correctly. Do I need to have jQuery 1.9+ in order to use jQuery Migrate 1.4.1? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/gitplaypen/js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

In the code above, "jquery.js" is jQuery 1.3.1. In the console I could see this:

```
JMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1
```